# How to read dates inside a file in php?

Tags: php, date, datetime-format, file-handling

I have a file in the format

```
1.start date: 15-04-2006

end date: 23-06-2006

2.start date: 03-06-2016

end date: 25-06-2016

3.start date: 01-10-2005

end date: 20-04-2015
```

I need to read this file using php and calculate the no of dates of form 19-month-year have passed between the start and end dates.

How can I read it in dates format rather than normal php file reading? What would be the best way to go about if I can't read it in dates format?

Comment: what file format is that? txt , json , doc or somethin else?

Comment: it's a .txt file.@RyanAW

Comment: I have tried to implement it by reading it as a normal text file but I feel that logic is very complicated for something that sounds so similar@lebelinoz